# How to find the positions of a digit in a String

Tags: java, numbers, java.util.scanner

```
Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Type the ten digit number");
String input=scanner.nextLine();
System.out.println("the input is"+input);
```

I'm use the above code. I want to find the position of the zeros in the given number.
For example 0123456780 the zero position is first and tenth. How can I find it?

Comment: Could u tell me how can add the position of strings..For Example if the zero comes 2 position and then 4 postion i want the result 24..how can i add that could u help me...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It uses regular expressions, so it can do the job even in more complex cases:

```
    String str = "03248923789320";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(0)");
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(str);
    while(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.start(0));
    }
```

I used regular expressions, because I assume you wouldn't have any problems in iterating the string and finding the positions of something so simple as '0'.

And if somehow the case is really that you need the indices of a single character faster solution will be:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == '0') {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could u tell me how can add the position of strings..For Example if the zero comes 2 position and then 4 postion i want the result 24..how can i add that could u help me...

Comment: Consider the second solution. Replace `System.out.println(i);` with `sb.append(i);`. Above the for cycle initialize `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();` Finally you get the result you want in `sb.toString();`

Comment: I want to write a java program to display some message every 15 minutes could anyone help to me?